# Execute OPA5 test headless and code coverage

Tags: tfs, phantomjs, sapui5, grunt-contrib-qunit

I am aware of using karma and phantomjs to run opa5 headless. I want to know if there any other options? Currently I am using grunt to run qunit and Nightwatch for unit and end-to-end tests. I added OPA5 tests and looking for ways to run it headlessly with coverage report which I can publish on TFS(Team Foundation Server)
Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You also can consider Selenium, check the different of them: Casperjs/PhantomJs vs Selenium.

Regarding test result, you can use trxReporter, related article: [CI/CD Pipeline for Angular2 with VSTS](http://www.clemensreijnen.nl/post/2016/10/17/CICD-Pipeline-for-Angular2-with-VSTS).

Regarding Code Coverage, the TFS Code Coverage supports JaCoco and Cobertura (Publish code coverage task) and karma-coverage supports Cobertura format, so you can use cobertura code coverage report.

Related article: [Include code coverage report in VSTS, Is Test Adapter mandatory for VSTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314239/include-code-coverage-report-in-vsts-is-test-adapter-mandatory-for-vsts) (Apply to TFS)