# Is it possible to integrate html report with VSTS build summary?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, karma-coverage

How do I integrate a html test results report generated by karma-htmlfile-reporter with VSTS build summary section? Any inputs will help

Answer (score 2):

There is no build-in way to achieve your requirement.

You could create your own extension to display graphical content (HTML page) in my VSTS/TFS summary page.

For example add a custom section in build result through your extension, with this way, you can add html test results report in that custom section.
There is the sample about build result extension: [vsts-extension-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/build-results-enhancer)

More information about how to build extension, you can refer to this article

[**Create your first extension for Visual Studio Team Services**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node)

A extension for your reference [Publish HTML Artifact](https://github.com/johnwalley/vsts-publish-html-artifact)

---

**Update**

Find another workaround, according to below reply in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314239/include-code-coverage-report-in-vsts-is-test-adapter-mandatory-for-vsts):

> VSTS Code coverage supports the outputted code coverage results in
>   Jacoco or Cobertura formats. *Karma-Coverage supports Cobertura
>   format.*
>
> Edit your karma.config.js for ....

Once you configure the output format, you could try to use [Publish Code Coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results?view=vsts) task to upload code coverage data to VSTS.

Comment: You can also vote for this feature request to be included in Azure Devops https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/491426/support-for-generic-html-publishing-inside-build-a.html

Answer (score 0):

**TFS** can understand a report if it is in the format of a format called **TRX**.

This can be achieved by using the `karma-trx-reporter` plugin in the `karma.conf.js`

Once the report is generated, we can then use [MSTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx) to publish the results

or you can upload using the [VSTS workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=vsts) function